# InvalidRequestError when make order in pybit

Tags: python, bybit, python-bybit, pybit

I want to test some codes for placing short-open orders using pybit.
My code is as follows.

```
from pybit import *
session = usdt_perpetual.HTTP(endpoint = "https://api-testnet.bybit.com",
                              api_key = 'yyyyy',
                              api_secret = 'xxxxxx')

symbol = "HIGHUSDT"
resp = session.place_active_order(
                                    symbol=symbol,
                                    side="Sell",
                                    order_type="Market",
                                    qty= 10,
                                    time_in_force="GoodTillCancel",
                                    reduce_only=False,
                                    close_on_trigger=False
                                )
```

It makes the following Error.

```
InvalidRequestError: Position idx not match position mode (ErrCode: 130001) (ErrTime: 01:35:30).
Request → POST https://api-testnet.bybit.com/private/linear/order/create: {'api_key': 'xxxxxxxx', 'close_on_trigger': False, 'order_type': 'Market', 'qty': 10, 'recv_window': 5000, 'reduce_only': False, 'side': 'Buy', 'symbol': 'HIGHUSDT', 'time_in_force': 'GoodTillCancel', 'timestamp': 1679362530091, 'sign': '64632a4ed529118f8516eb01294deec4036289ae835326eb24abef6b1ab8b813'}.
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?
I changed qty and order_type, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you use hedge mode for the futures contract, so the error is that the "positionIdx" parameter is not set. I also recommend upgrading to the latest version of the pybit library, because the code above shows that you are still using the v3 REST API, but there is a newer version REST API v5.

**There are two solutions**:

1. Use single mode, in this mode the parameter "positionIdx" is not mandatory.
2. Use hedge mode and set "positionIdx" parameter.

**What is Hedge mode?**

- When you trade with One-Way Mode, your positions can be open only in one direction - Long or Short.
- Hedge Mode allows you to keep a Long and Short position at the same time for your same trading pair.

**PositionIdx parameter setting rules**

Used to identify positions in different position modes. Under hedge-mode, this param is required

```
0: one-way mode
1: hedge-mode Buy side
2: hedge-mode Sell side
```

**Code example for hedge mode**

```py
from pybit.unified_trading import HTTP

class UpdatingTakeProfitAndStopLossActivePosition(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_place_active_order(self):
        pybit_client = HTTP(
            testnet=True,
            api_key="",
            api_secret=""
        )

        response = pybit_client.place_order(
            category="linear",
            symbol="HIGHUSDT",
            side="Sell",
            orderType="Market",
            qty="10",
            timeInForce="GTC",
            reduceOnly=False,
            closeOnTrigger=False,
            positionIdx=2
        )

        print("Response: {}".format(response))

        self.assertEqual(response["retCode"], 0)
        self.assertEqual(response["retMsg"], "OK")
```

**requirements.txt**

```
pybit==5.3.0
```

**Response example**

```json
{'retCode': 0, 'retMsg': 'OK', 'result': {'orderId': '0dab0e8c-7468-405a-9905-4dfc1f0ddf92', 'orderLinkId': ''}, 'retExtInfo': {}, 'time': 1685470503583}
```

**Links**

- [Bybit rest api v5 doc - create-order method](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/order/create-order)